# The argument 'length' is smaller than minimum of '1' (Parameter 'length' ) in Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am calling an azure function from my azure data factory. the function takes a json array as the body. I am able to run the function from Postman but when I try to call it from Azure data factory, I get error as

> " [Error] Executed 'Function1' (Failed,
> Id=a48a3829-e923-4c12-bc8d-edaa2ff04c43, Duration=284ms)The argument
> 'length' is smaller than minimum of '1' (Parameter 'length')"

The body is same as passed in Postman as in ADF. Why this weird behaviour. Anyone Anyidea? I dont hv any other parameter as length.

Comment: The error implies it is missing parameter. Have you configured parameter in Azure function app,  Are you sure there is data when you are passing the POST body, try to debug or test just the azure function as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#:~:text=query%20string%20values.-,CreateHttpRequest,-%3A%20This%20method%20creates) Try to jsonify the body if not sure like `@json(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value))`